# Python removing specific marks from the list

Tags: python, list

I have this kind of list:

```
['8 ', '27', '90+1 ','27','90+3','47']
```

My goal is to get it like this:

```
['8', '27','90','27','90','47']
```

How I can remove the "+" marks and next numbers from the list?

Comment: So you remove `+1` and `+3`, you do *not* want to calculate it?

Comment: Can a item have multiple '+' or single '+'?

Comment: Just use `.split()`. And try to do something by yourself for once, rather than asking others for such a trivial task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
[x.split('+',1)[0] for x in data]
```

With `data` the original list:

```
>>> [x.split('+',1)[0] for x in data]
['8 ', '27', '90', '27', '90', '47']
```

We thus use `split()` to convert the string into a list of substrings, splitted by `+`. The `1` is optional, but will prevent the system from create more elements. Then we take the first sublist.

Answer (score 5):

using regex to remove plus and following chars sounds a logical way to do it:

```
import re

l = ['8 ', '27', '90+1 ','27','90+3','47']

newl = [re.sub("\+.*","",x) for x in l]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would build a method that takes in a string, checks if it has the '+' sign in it and removes it and everything after it.

Like so:

```
def cleanmark(string):
    if "+" in string:
        return string.split('+')[0]
    return string
```

Then I would map it on the original list.

```
a = ['8 ', '27', '90+1 ','27','90+3','47']
a = map(lambda x: cleanmark(x), a)
```

This should be sufficient for removal of the '+' content.

Comment: Python 3 needs converting to list. Map doesnt do it anymore

Comment: Also remove lambda since you made a function. Just pass cleanmark

Comment: Thanks for the advice, fair point on Python 3, only tried the code out on 2.7

Answer (score 2):

Do something like:

```
original_list = ['8 ', '27', '90+1 ','27','90+3','47']
list_modified = [item.split('+')[0] for item in original_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this process :

```
list = ['8 ', '27', '90+1 ','27','90+3','47']
list1 = []
for k in list:
    if '+' in k:
        list1.append(k.split('+')[0])
    else:
        list1.append(k)

print(list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

> How I can remove the "+" marks and next numbers from the list?

My interpretation for this sentence, is that you want to update the current list and not create a new one, as all the other answers do. This way you avoid using twice the memory needed and it's probably faster.

```
def remove_plus_marks(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        k = l[i].find('+')
        if k != -1:
            l[i] = l[i][:k]
```

Here we are editing the current list instead of creating a new one, so we don't have to do memory allocations for all items. We also use the `find` method instead of `split` because it is faster.